How to make a view on pg_user_info to select user details in Redshift?
I need a way to copy the list of all the users and their account details from pg_user_info of Redshift database. I need different details like if the account is active or not etc.
I tried to fetch the details from pg_user but they were not enough. I tried to make a custom role but I was not able to do that as well.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

pg_user_info is a superuser only view so only Redshift users with superuser privileges can access it.  To gain superuser privileges another superuser will need to grant you "CREATE USER" rights.
ALTER USER <you> CREATEUSER;

Please reply if this isn't the issue you are encountering as it isn't completely clear from the post.
Also once you are a superuser you may not be able to create the desired view as I suspect pg_user_info is a leader-only view and cannot be combined with other compute-node data.  It is not clear if this is your intent or not but be aware.
